# When using vue.js, the radio button is not mapped to the v-model normally if repeated with v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'd like to make a big change to this code. But it doesn't work the way I want it to.

```
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" v-model="options.prdtType" value="CODE001">
        <i></i>
        <span class="txt">A</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" v-model="options.prdtType" value="CODE002">
        <i></i>
        <span class="txt">B</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" v-model="options.prdtType" value="CODE003">
        <i></i>
        <span class="txt">C</span>
    </label>
</td>
```

And this is the code I changed.

```
data: {
    codeVo: {
        codeObsTypeList: [],                
              
    },
    ...
    userParam: {                              
        prdtType: '',                    
    }
 ...

<td>
    <label class="radio_custom" v-for="(item, index) in codeVo.codeObsTypeList" :key="index">
        <input type="radio" v-model="userParam.prdtType" v-value="item.key">
        <i></i>
        <span class="txt" v-text="item.txt"></span>
    </label>
</td>
```

And codeVo.codeObsTypeList is like this.

[image]

Comment: Any chance for CodeSandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can `v-value="item.key"` change to `:value="item.key`.

```
<td>
    <label class="radio_custom" v-for="(item, index) in codeVo.codeObsTypeList" :key="index">
        <input type="radio" v-model="userParam.prdtType" :value="item.key">
        <i></i>
        <span class="txt" v-text="item.txt"></span>
    </label>
</td>
```